# Count pages of another worksheet in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Moin,
I have a workbook with multiple worksheets and i want to create a button, which lets you send the worksheet you have on your screen right now via email. My concept is working for the first worksheet, but when i move on and try to do the same thing in the second worksheet it does not work.

The reason i found for the ExportAsFixedFormat to import the wrong pages is, that my start was set wrong. Now i'm trying to get this right. My plan was to get the length (amount of pages) of the first worksheet and set the start for the second worksheet at `1 + lenght of first worksheet`.

My problem now: i didnt find an opportunity to get the length of the first worksheet.

That is my code:

```
 
'** Dimensionierung der Variablen
Dim strPDF As String
Dim OutlookApp As Object, strEmail As Object
 
'** Vorgaben definieren
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set strEmail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

'**Reporttyp feststellen
Dim Datum As String
Dim Sheet As String
Dim Reporttype As Integer

Sheet = CStr(ActiveSheet.Name)

If Sheet = "Tagesbericht" Then
    Reporttype = 1
ElseIf Sheet = "Wochenbericht" Then
    Reporttype = 2
ElseIf Sheet = "Monatsbericht" Then
    Reporttype = 3
End If

'**Datum/Zeitraum des Reports bestimmen
If Reporttype = 1 Then
    Datum = CStr(Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("G4"))
ElseIf Reporttype = 2 Then
    Datum = CStr(Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("J4"))
ElseIf Reporttype = 3 Then
    Datum = Cells(2, 10).Value
End If

'** Druckbereich festlegen
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:J156"
End With

'** Datum von Tagesbericht ausgeben lassen


'** Druckbereich definieren
Dim Reportstart As Integer
Dim Reportlength As Integer
Dim aktuelles_blatt As Integer
Dim Length_TR As Integer

'Reportend = False
'zeile = 1

'For zeileloop = 1 To 10000
'   CheckCell = Range("G" & zeileloop)
'    If IsEmpty(CheckCell) = True Then
'        zeile = zeileloop
'        zeileloop = 10000
'    End If
'Next zeileloop

Sheets(1).Activate
Length_TR = ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.DOCUMENT(50)")
Sheets(2).Activate

Cells(2, 14).Value = Length_TR

aktuelles_blatt = ActiveSheet.Index
If Reporttype = 1 Then
    Reportstart = 1
ElseIf Reporttype = 2 Then
    Reportstart = CInt(1 + Length_TR)
End If
Reportlength = ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.DOCUMENT(50)")


Cells(1, 14).Value = Reportlength

If Reporttype = 1 Then
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Zoom = 90
ElseIf Reporttype = 2 Then
ElseIf Reporttype = 3 Then
End If

'** Empfänger auswählen Dropdownliste
Dim Empfaenger As String
Empfaenger = ComboBox1.Value
 
'** PDF erzeugen
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
 ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name & " " & Datum & " BER.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard _
 , IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, From:=Reporttype, To:=Reportlength, OpenAfterPublish _
 :=True 'True wieder auf Flase ändern wenn fertig

'** E-Mail versenden
strPDF = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name & " " & Datum & " BER.pdf"
With strEmail
  .To = Empfaenger
  .Subject = ActiveSheet.Name & " " & Datum & " BER " 'Betreffzeile
  .body = "Dies ist ein Automatisch erzeugter Bericht. Bitte beachten Sie die PDF im Anhang."
  .Attachments.Add strPDF
  .Display
'  .Send 'Damit wir die E-Mail sofort versendet
  Kill strPDF
End With
   
'** Objektvariablen wieder löschen
Set OutlookApp = Nothing
Set strEmail = Nothing
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
End With
End Sub
```

Worksheet 1 is named "Tagesbericht" and worksheet 2 is "Wochenbericht".

Comment: Is there a button on each worksheet, or a button on the ribbon to send the currently active worksheet?

Comment: Have you tried to use [ExportAsFixedFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.exportasfixedformat) from a Worksheet and not from the Workbook? (so you don't need parameters _from_ and _to_)

Comment: I think it would be simpler to make a copy of the sheet in a new workbook then export that entire workbook as a pdf. I'm not that familiar, but it seems a bit strange the way excel counts pages. I would also recommend either storing the workbook name as an string or the workbook as an object once you get it once rather than repeatedly using ```ActiveSheet```. Better yet if each sheet will have it's own button just make the sheet name a parameter and have the button call the sub with the sheet name.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have a button in each worksheet and appointed a macro to it that launched a UserForm whose code is the one here.

Comment: I implemented your advices and know it works how i imagined it to work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my problem was to change the `ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat` to `Worksheets([Sheetname]).ExportAsFixedFormat`. I also replaced the repetitive `ActiveSheet` with a variable called "Sheet", which is defined as the ActiveSheet in the beginning.

Thanks @Shrotter and @Basbadger for the help!

Here is my new Code:

```
 
'** Dimensionierung der Variablen
Dim strPDF As String
Dim OutlookApp As Object, strEmail As Object
 
'** Vorgaben definieren
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set strEmail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

'**Reporttyp feststellen
Dim Datum As String
Dim Sheet As String
Dim Reporttype As Integer

Sheet = CStr(ActiveSheet.Name)

If Sheet = "Tagesbericht" Then
    Reporttype = 1
ElseIf Sheet = "Wochenbericht" Then
    Reporttype = 2
ElseIf Sheet = "Monatsbericht" Then
    Reporttype = 3
End If

'**Datum/Zeitraum des Reports bestimmen
If Reporttype = 1 Then
    Datum = CStr(Worksheets(Sheet).Range("G4"))
ElseIf Reporttype = 2 Then
    Datum = CStr(Worksheets(Sheet).Range("J4"))
ElseIf Reporttype = 3 Then
    Datum = Cells(2, 10).Value
End If

'** Druckbereich festlegen
With Worksheets(Sheet).PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:J156"
End With

'** Datum von Tagesbericht ausgeben lassen


'** Druckbereich definieren
Dim Reportstart As Integer
Dim Reportlength As Integer
Dim aktuelles_blatt As Integer
Dim Length_TR As Integer

If Reporttype = 1 Then
    Worksheets(Sheet).PageSetup.Zoom = 90
ElseIf Reporttype = 2 Then
ElseIf Reporttype = 3 Then
    Worksheets(Sheet).PageSetup.Zoom = 83
End If

'** Empfänger auswählen Dropdownliste
Dim Empfaenger As String
Empfaenger = ComboBox1.Value
 
'** PDF erzeugen
Worksheets(Sheet).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
 ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name & " " & Datum & " BER.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard _
 , IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish _
 :=False

'** E-Mail versenden
strPDF = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name & " " & Datum & " BER.pdf"
With strEmail
  .To = Empfaenger
  .Subject = Worksheets(Sheet).Name & " " & Datum & " BER " 'Betreffzeile
  .body = "Dies ist ein Automatisch erzeugter Bericht. Bitte beachten Sie die PDF im Anhang."
  .Attachments.Add strPDF
  .Display
'  .Send 'Damit wir die E-Mail sofort versendet
  Kill strPDF
End With
   
'** Objektvariablen wieder löschen
Set OutlookApp = Nothing
Set strEmail = Nothing
With Worksheets(Sheet).PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
End With
End Sub
```